# Making Ctrl-C copy from whichever SourceViewer has focus in Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I successfully extended the PyDev editor in Eclipse with a [side-by-side display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11402278/4794), but I can't copy the contents of the extra SourceViewer that I added. I can select some text in the display, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it always copies the main PyDev editor's selected text.

I found an article on [key bindings in Eclipse editors](http://greensopinion.blogspot.ca/2009/10/key-bindings-in-eclipse-editors.html), but the code there seems incomplete and a bit out-of-date. How can I configure the copy command to copy from whichever SourceViewer has focus?

The reason I want to do this is that I've written a tool for [live coding in Python](http://donkirkby.github.com/live-py-plugin/), and it would be much easier for users to submit bug reports if they could just copy the display and paste it into the bug description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[David Green's article](http://greensopinion.blogspot.ca/2009/10/key-bindings-in-eclipse-editors.html) was a good start, but it took a bit of digging to make it all work. I published a full [example project](https://github.com/donkirkby/side-py-side) on GitHub, and I'll post a couple of snippets here.

The `TextViewerSupport` class wires up a new action handler for each command you want to delegate to the extra text viewer. If you have multiple text viewers, just instantiate a `TextViewerSupport` object for each of them. It wires up everything in its constructor.

```
public TextViewerSupport(TextViewer textViewer) {
    this.textViewer = textViewer;
    StyledText textWidget = textViewer.getTextWidget();
    textWidget.addFocusListener(this);
    textWidget.addDisposeListener(this);

    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    handlerService = (IHandlerService) window
            .getService(IHandlerService.class);

    if (textViewer.getTextWidget().isFocusControl()) {
        activateContext();
    }
}
```

The `activateContext()` method has a list of all the commands you want to delegate, and registers a new handler for each one. This was one of the changes from David's article; his `ITextEditorActionDefinitionIds` has been deprecated and replaced with `IWorkbenchCommandConstants`.

```
protected void activateContext() {
    if (handlerActivations.isEmpty()) {
        activateHandler(ITextOperationTarget.COPY,
                IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_COPY);
    }
}

// Add a single handler.
protected void activateHandler(int operation, String actionDefinitionId) {
    StyledText textWidget = textViewer.getTextWidget();
    IHandler actionHandler = createActionHandler(operation,
            actionDefinitionId);
    IHandlerActivation handlerActivation = handlerService.activateHandler(
            actionDefinitionId, actionHandler,
            new ActiveFocusControlExpression(textWidget));

    handlerActivations.add(handlerActivation);
}

// Create a handler that delegates to the text viewer.
private IHandler createActionHandler(final int operation,
        String actionDefinitionId) {
    Action action = new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (textViewer.canDoOperation(operation)) {
                textViewer.doOperation(operation);
            }
        }
    };
    action.setActionDefinitionId(actionDefinitionId);
    return new ActionHandler(action);
}
```

The [`ActiveFocusControlExpression`](https://github.com/donkirkby/side-py-side/blob/master/src/com/github/donkirkby/sidepyside/ActiveFocusControlExpression.java) gives the new handler a high enough priority that it will replace the standard handler, and it's almost identical to David's version. However, to get it to compile, I had to add extra dependencies to my plug-in manifest: I imported packages `org.eclipse.core.expressions` and `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor`.